# jsf component rendering issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

```
<h:commandLink value="Request Permission" rendered="#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus} eq null?true:false">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{DocData}" target="#{requestController.docResult}" />
                                                   </h:commandLink>

<h:outputText value="#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus}" rendered="#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus} eq 'Request Pending'?true:false">
```

In the above code, I have a `commandlink` and an `outputtext`. I am rendering them on some condition.

1. `commandlink` would render when `"#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus}` would be null.
2. `outputtext` would render when `"#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus}`would equal to a String value *"Request Pending"*.

But, when I run this code, it shows nothing. Neither the *commandlink* nor the *outputtext*.

I want to know what I am doing wrong here.

Is the condition `#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus} eq null?true:false"` or anything else wrong? I have tested by printing values on same xhtml page of `#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus}` to make sure that even I am getting the values or not, and they are present.

Comment: shouldnt it be like `rendered="#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus eq 'Request Pending'? true:false}"`

Comment: yes it is ... please post it as your answer so i accept it

Comment: The `?true:false` parts are completely unnecessary. The comparison returns a boolean already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rendered="#{dataTableWidgetVar.permissionStatus eq 'Request Pending'? true:false}"
```

Comment: plz leave a comment after down voting!